# Глобальный Класс Java EE

Tags: java-ee, lib, global-variables

Может я не так выражаюсь говоря "Глобальные переменные" но штука вот в чём.

Пишу уже какой проект. Выделил для себя довольно таки хорошее кол-во похожего функционала. Решил его вынести в свою либу - jar файл. Создал класс, перенес функционал, скомпилил, подключил в проекте, вызвал при помощи new и т.д. - всё хорошо.

Тут я задался вопросом. Я создал обёртку для всех классов, так скажем, SERVER. Как этот класс сделать глобальным?

Под глобальностью я имею в виду то что я могу напрямую обратиться к своему классу с данными из сервлеты. Тобишь когда создается контейнер сервлет при первом подключении клиента, создавался экземпляр класса `SERVER` и был доступен везде для этого клиента. У каждого клиента свой класс.

Спасибо.

Comment: Вы можете передать его через конструктор

Comment: @etki в смысле?

Comment: Я ничего не понял. Что значит "глобальные переменные" _request, который приходит в сервлету_? Почему request глобальный?

Comment: @Tachkin обновил шапку.

Comment: Понятнее не стало. Тебе надо иметь доступ к объекту своего пакета из пула потоков сервера? Пропиши ссылку в контекст приложения. Или что то другое?

Comment: В прямом, можете передать его в конструктор сервлета и таким образом пользоваться им в самом сервлете.

Comment: @Tachkin как бы так. Когда подключается новый клиент создаётся контейнер сервлет, тобишь отдельный поток в котором находятся экземпяры классов. Тобишь для каждого юзера свой поток и свои данные. Я хочу что бы мой класс точно так же создавался для каждого клиента и доступ к нему был прямо в сервлете.

Comment: @etki пример, пожалуйста)

Comment: Один экземпляр на запрос? Или один экземпляр на приложение?

Comment: @Tachkin Всё таки на запрос да.

Comment: Я искренне верю, что конструктор вы можете написать и сами

Comment: Я сейчас страшную вещь скажу, но проще всего инициализировать объект в стеке запроса, т.е. new в самом сервлете или в фильтре прописать (связанность увеличится, конечно). Ioc контейнер есть? можно из него выдирать. Море вариантов на самом деле.

Comment: @Tachkin loc контейнера нет. не знаю что это. Я сейчас что я и делаю что создаю в самой сервлете. Но мне приходится это делать в каждой сервлете отдельно.

Comment: @Tachkin можно по подробней об ioc контейнере?

Comment: Обозвал я просто не распространенным образом. DI контейнер. Spring там или Google Guice, короче CDI, если EE стек брать.